# ASP.NET 5 multiple dbcontext problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm playing around with the new ASP.NET 5 beta 8 and having trouble when I have two dbcontext.

I have the following project structure.

```
-Data(Identity 3 db with other entities)
-Resources (Contains a db with translations)
-WebApp
```

Stripped away some code in Startup.cs in WebApp

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MainDb:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ResourceDbContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:Resources:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddTransient<IResourceDbContext, ResourceDbContext>();
        services.AddTransient<IDatabaseContext, DatabaseContext>();
}
```

In both ResourceDbContext and DatabaseContext I do the following

```
    public ResourceDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        _connectionString = ((SqlServerOptionsExtension)options.Extensions.First()).ConnectionString;
    }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
    }
```

However when I read my connectionstrings from appsettings.json I receive the correct values in ConfigureServices. But the DbContextOptions only contains the latest loaded value, in this case the connectionstring for Resources. So both dbcontext establishes a connection to Resource db.

I'm unable to find any information about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is indicate that DbContextOptions is a generic type:

```
public ResourceDbContext(DbContextOptions<ResourceDbContext> options) : base(options)
{

}
```

Now the dependency injection system can find the right dependency (`DbContextOptions options`) at the moment it creates ResourceDbContext and injects it into the constructor.

[See implementation AddDbContext method](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework.Core/Infrastructure/EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.cs#L68-L77)

---

For Miroslav Siska:

```
public class GetHabitsIdentity: IdentityDbContext<GetHabitsUser, IdentityRole, string> where TUser : IdentityUser
{
    public GetHabitsIdentity(DbContextOptions<GetHabitsIdentity> options)
        :base(options)
    {

    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use EF with different coonection strings. I don't see the error in your code. I used this setup.

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:OtherConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

In the DBContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Localizations> Localizations { get; set; }
    private string _connectionString;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        _connectionString = ((SqlServerOptionsExtension)optionsBuilder.Options.Extensions.First()).ConnectionString;
        Console.WriteLine($"ApplicationDbContext{_connectionString}");
    }


public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    private string _connectionString;

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        _connectionString = ((SqlServerOptionsExtension)optionsBuilder.Options.Extensions.First()).ConnectionString;
        Console.WriteLine($"ApplicationContext{_connectionString}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for big help!!!

Complete solution:

```
  public class TenantDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    private string _connectionString { get; set; }  

    public TenantDbContext(DbContextOptions<TenantDbContext> options) : base(options)  
    {
        this._connectionString = "Connection String";
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    { 
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_connectionString); 
    }
}
```

ASP.NET 5 DI working for injecting DbContext and UserManager to controller. Now it is possible to login and register with multiple databases... Now I need only check how to inject connection string here: this._connectionString = "Connection String"; But it is simple... Thank you again!